# Calculate the area of the region in the first quadrant...

Tags: integration, area

Calculate the area of the region in the first quadrant bounded by the
curves $4y = x, x^2y = 16, $ and $xy = 16.$

[image: My solution]

Was I right in adding the area under $y = 16/x^2$ from 8 to 4 back in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making this more complicated than it needs to be. Why not just split the shaded region up into two regions, one from $x=1$ to $x=4$ and the other from $x=4$ to $x=8$. Then the area is
\begin{equation*}
  \int_1^4 \left(\frac{16}{x} - \frac{16}{x^2}\right)\,dx
      + \int_4^8 \left(\frac{16}{x} - \frac{x}{4}\right)\,dx.
\end{equation*}

Comment: Oh damn it, didn't even consider that. Is my solution right though?

Comment: I don't know. I didn't compute it. But you can compute both and see.